# How to add python module to system path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install the following tool for use on the command line on the Ubuntu desktop:

https://github.com/crytic/slither

The installation instructions are straight-forward:

```
pip3 install slither-analyzer
```

and then simply run the tool like this:

```
slither .
```

I'm able to install it successfully but the problem is that when I run 'slither .' I get the following error message:

```
slither: command not found
```

I don't know how to add the tool to the path, (or even how to execute it at all) as I don't normally work with Python.  I'd appreciate any help from someone who works with Python and can see where I'm going wrong.

This my version of Python:

```
Python 3.8.10
```

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Have you tried to add this command to system PATH?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-from-anywhere-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

That can easily be the result of having different versions of Python installed on your machine. There's a simple workaround: Try preceding your command with `python3 -m` or `python3.8 -m`.

Eg:

```sh
python3 -m slither

python3.8 -m slither
```

That sets which Python to use, as your command might only be installed for a specific version of Python. Scripts would live in that Python's `bin` folder on a Linux machine.